# MySql: Load Data file, temporary columns

Tags: mysql, load, temporary

I have the following data structure in .CSV file:

```
Name       Month1     Month2     Month3
Name1       40          20         10
Name2       14          10         11
```

I need to load this data in the following structure

```
Name    Month   Value
Name1    1       40
Name1    2       20
...
```

My idea is execute a load data file inside a looping. The first time, read only Month1 info, in the second time, load only Month2 info and beyond.

My load data file code will be something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE demo.test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'                
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'              
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES  
(NAME, @var1, @var2, @var3)
SET QTD = @var1;
```

Is there any way to define @var1 dynamically? So, for the first interaction temporary variable used to define QTD will be "var1", on the second interaction will be "var2", etc.

Regards,

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible with a `WHILE` loop (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html). You could also just load the CSV file into a staging table as is, and use `INSERT INTO` to populate the final tables (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Comment: 2nd option in previous comment. Dont do the first..much slower.

Comment: Jup you need to use a staging table where you import the table a use a unpivot method or column to record convertion (use UNION ALL) so you need two queries for this.... Or you create you own CVS parser with MySQL's LOAD_FILE() ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file ) function in combination with some SQL number generators and nested SUBSTRING_INDEX functions so you can split records and columns from that CVS file which you use as a delivered table for a INSERT INTO ... SELECT query..